# Who was 赵王 after 赵奢 in 赵国?

Tags: history

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 15:

几年后，赵奢去世了。这一年正好秦国军队来打赵国，赵国派老将廉颇带20万大军迎战。

...

这时，赵王正因廉颇闭门不战而生气呢，听到外面的那些谣言，果然上当了，他派赵括去换回廉颇。

So I wonder, who was 赵王 after 赵奢 in 赵国? Did he have a full name?

Comment: The context doesn't tell. Or you ask about  history?

Comment: Yes, history question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[赵奢](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B5%B5%E5%A5%A2/345507) was not a 赵王, he was a famous general of 赵国 who served 赵武灵王、赵惠文王 and 赵孝成王. So at the time of 赵奢's death, the king of 赵国 was [赵孝成王](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B5%B5%E5%AD%9D%E6%88%90%E7%8E%8B/3252665?fromModule=lemma_inlink), 赵丹

The king after [赵孝成王], 赵丹 was  [赵悼襄王], 赵偃